# svn branching problem

Tags: svn

i have my source at /tmp/easton/ having two folder 1 src and 2 Webroot. 
now i do svn checkout at /var/www/html/easton folder.

after i have to import this two 1. src(contain java files) 2. Webroot(/WEB_INF/classes) to my /var/www/html/easton. for this i have done
**svn import /tmp/easton svn://localhost/easton** this creat two folder in repository.

Now i have to checkout my WebRoot directory to /var/www/html/easton.
for that i go to **cd /var/www/html/easton** then **svn co svn://localhost/easton/Webroot**

now here its create WebRoot directory to /var/www/html/easton.

Here my doubt is i dont want to create WebRoot directory to /var/www/html/easton. but copy all folders to my /var/www/html/easton.

for e.g
in my  WebRoot have two folder 1. WEB-INF 2. pages. 
so i want to copy this two to /var/www/html/easton/ WEB-INF..Pages.

please help me into this. This is svn branching. when i fire commit command at my local it update source code at both /var/www/html/easton/.. and also at /tmp/easton/ src and WebRoot also.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion (and every other version control software I know) is not interested in into which directory you locally checked out the source or data.

I find the question a bit difficult to understand but if I understood you well you do not want to modify the repository on commit in the same way for different local copies (different checked out directories). To do that you indeed need several related directories in subversion, if you want to misuse subversion to deploy data to these directories. ( I say misuse but it is not meant negative, there are scenarios where deploying with subversion makes your life easier)

If the different directories contain completely different data, then branching is not for you, just create different directories in subversion and checkout each one to one of your local directories. (But I guess that you already know)

Now comes the easy part: for subversion branching is just like creating a copy. To detach one directory from the same subversion directory you would need:

1. Branch / create a copy of your directory
2. Switch one of the local directories to that branch DirA
3. Make the changes for that branch in dirA
4. Commit on dirA (these changes will go only to the branch)

Now if you want to update the branch with new content from the point where you branched from you will need to merge. An alternative for parts that have to be the same in both branches is to use [`svn:externals`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html)

I hope this helps and is what you wanted to know.